# Flask:Confused over using PUT/POST in Rest API

Tags: rest, python-requests, flask-restful

Respected Elders/Programmers/Learned-people,
I have read a very popular answer here about using PUT or POST, but I couldn't decipher from it as to what is the correct way to do so. Almost every answer has comments saying this is wrong/this is right. Mighty confused here.
My requirements:
Sending 2 Json files to the server, one to be inserted in Database and other to be updated. I thought I would use PUT to update, and POST to Insert into the database. That way, on the client side itself I would decide whether to insert or update.

Confusion: Since, the client alone is responsible for its data to be created/updated on the server, even POST in my case upon being repeated would insert the same thing (`insert into table values`) over and over, behaving as idempotent  OR would give an error (Because of primary key conflict). Finally, it would not create something new upon firing it twice.

Question: Is it correct to use PUT for updation, and POST for insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PUT` can also be used for creating. What's important is the url. This is *generally* the accepted pattern:

```
PUT /collection/1234 <- Update a specific item OR create it
POST /collection <- Add a new item to a collection
```

Which one is right for you depends on a few things. Does the server determine the url of the new item, or does the client?

If the client can figure out what the url of a new item becomes, using `PUT` might be better because you can more easily turn it into an idempotent request.

Remember that with a `PUT` request the intent is always that you are *replacing* the resource at the target url with a new state.

However, if the server creates the url pattern (maybe you have an auto-incrementing id), POST is better. POST doesn't *have* to be on the parent collection but it's common.

If you want `POST` and want idempotence, you need some other way to figure out something was a repeated request. You get that for free with `PUT`. For example, the Stripe API [solves](https://stripe.com/en-ca/blog/idempotency) this by adding a non-standard `Idempotency-Key` header.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. Your lines - "Which one is right for ... or does the client?" has ended all of my confusions about its proper usage. Thank you once again.